# unable to load the node modules in angular2+hapijs

Tags: angular

I referred the below link for my project,

https://github.com/ptpaterson/hapi-angular-quickstart

But I am unable to load the node_modules mentioned in index.html in browser using hapi and angular 2, not even the styles.css file, its showing not found(404) error.

Any help would be appreciated.

[The error occured while running the angular 2 in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pd9Sp.png)

Comment: Resolved :
For each and every link provided in 'index.html' and 'systemjs.config.js' file need to add ```quickstart/``` at starting. For example: <link rel="stylesheet" href="```quickstart/```styles.css">.
Otherwise can remove routes in server.js. [```routes: { prefix: '/quickstart' }```]